# Removing duplicates as well as the corresponding values from array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and I want to remove values from an array that appear more than once. I have the following:

```
arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9]
```

and the result should be:

```
arr = [1,3,4,5,7,8,9].
```

What would be the simplest, shortest Ruby code to accomplish this?

Comment: A combination of `group_by`, `select` and `map` will do the trick

Comment: Is your array always / already sorted?

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for the reply. Yes, the Array would always be already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sergio Tulentsev mentioned combination of group_by and select will do the trick
Here you go

```
arr.group_by{|i| i}.select{|k, v| v.count.eql?(1)}.keys
```

Comment: @Rohit Kumar - Thank you so much, this one does exactly what I require:

arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9]

arr.group_by{|i| i}.select{|k, v| v.count.eql?(1)}.keys  => [1,3,4,5,7,8,9].

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this by array `select` and `count` methods

```
arr.select { |x| arr.count(x) == 1 } #=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: O(N^2) complexity. Could be better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_duplicates(elements)
    encountered = {}

    # Examine all elements in the array.
    elements.each do |e|
        # If the element is in the hash, it is a duplicate.
        if encountered[e]
            #Remove the element
        else
            # Record that the element was encountered.
            encountered[e] = 1
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you test this mate, i see each would return original array

Comment: @gates: this is probably a pointer kind of answer. To give some ideas, not provide complete solution

Comment: Not right now I am from a phone so I cannot test it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove values from an array that appear more than once.

- to check element appear more than once use **[Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count)**
- to remove element conditionally use **[Array#delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)**

below is an example:

```
> arr.delete_if{|e| arr.count(e) > 1}
#=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Option2:**

```
> arr.group_by{|e| e}.delete_if{|_,v| v.size > 1}.keys
#=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

First of you need to group elements by itself (which will return key, value pair), then remove such elements which appear more than once(value), and use `keys`

Comment: Thanks to all for the effort and your brilliant answers. Your help is always appreciated.

Comment: @RobinWood : Glad to help you. You can accept the answer which solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use a *counting hash*.

**Code**

```
def single_instances(arr) 
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }.
      select { |_,v| v == 1 }.
      keys
end
```

**Example**

```
single_instances [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9]
  #=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9]

f = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
```

`f` is created with the method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with an argument of zero. That means that if `f` does not have a key `k`, `f[k]` returns zero (and does not alter `f`).

```
enum = arr.each_with_object(f)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]:each_with_object({})>
h = enum.each { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>2, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}
g = h.select { |_,v| v == 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}
g.keys
  #=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

In calculating `g`, [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) (which returns a hash), not [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (which returns an array), is executed. I've used an underscore for the first block variable (a key in `h`) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.

Let's look more carefully at the calculation of `h`. The first value is generated by the enumerator `enum` and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values using a process called *disambiguation* or *decomposition*.

```
e, h = enum.next
  #=> [1, {}]
e #=> 1
h #=> {}
```

so the block calculation is

```
h[e] += 1
  #=> h[e] = h[e] + 1 => 0 + 1 => 1
```

`h[e]` on the right side of the equality (using the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), as contrasted with [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) on the left side of the equality), returns `1` because `h` has no key `e #=> 1`.

The next two elements of `enum` are passed to the block and the following calculations are performed.

```
e, h = enum.next
  #=> [2, {1=>1}]
h[e] += 1
  #=> h[e] = h[2] + 1 => 0 + 1 => 1
```

Notice that `h` has been updated.

```
e, h = enum.next
  #=> [2, {1=>1, 2=>1}]
h[e] += 1
  #=> h[e] = h[e] + 1 => h[2] + 1 => 1 + 1 => 2 
h #=> {1=>1, 2=>2}
```

This time, because `h` already has a key `e #=> 2`, the hash's default value is not used.

The remaining calculations are similar.

**Use `[Array#difference]` instead**

A simpler way is to use the method `Array#difference`.

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

Suppose

```
arr = [1,2,2,3,4,2,5,6,6,7,8,9]
```

Note the addition of a third `2`.

```
arr - arr.difference(arr.uniq)
  # => [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

The three steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = arr.difference(a)
  #=> [2, 2, 6] (elements that appear more than once)
arr - b
  # => [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

I've proposed that `Array#diffence` be [added to the Ruby core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815), but there seems to be little interest in doing so.